# type tag is not removed even though @SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC) declared in jax-ws while creating wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I want to create a wsdl using jax-ws. For this I've used @webServcice annotations.

Below are java source code
1.Interface

```
package com.soap.business;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import com.soap.modal.Product;
@WebService(name="getprod")
public interface GetInfoIface { 
    public Product getNameProduct(String name);
}
```

2. Java bean

```
String name;
String category;
String type;
//setters, getters
```

3. Implementation class

   @WebService( portName="ProdNamePort", serviceName="ProductNameService")
   @SOAPBinding(style=Style.RPC)
   public class GetInfoIfaceImpl implements GetInfoIface {
       @WebMethod(action="prod-name", operationName="getProdName")
       @WebResult(name="Product")
       public Product getNameProduct(String name) {

   ```
       Product ab= new Product();
       return ab;
   }
   ```

   }

when I deploy and check for wsdl ,  I did see type tag found along xsd,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D04K5.png)

```
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://business.soap.com/" schemaLocation="http://surya:8080/CreateWSDL/ProductNameService?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
```

when I go and check for http://surya:8080/CreateWSDL/ProductNameService?xsd=1 url i did see like below xsd was imported

```
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://business.soap.com/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://business.soap.com/">
<xs:element name="Product" type="tns:product"/>
<xs:complexType name="product">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="category" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

can't I import this directly into my wsdl, this makes me trouble when create mock service the above wsdl. SOAP ui not able create project if copy the wsdl and store in local, SOAP ui create project when I refer webservice run on my local mechine. Can any one help me how to do figure out this. Thank you